# wpa_cli connection to hidden ssid

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wpa-cli

I have a raspberrypi ZeroW that I am trying to connect to a network with a hidden ssid. I know that I could add this line "scan_ssid=1" to my wpa_supplicant.conf file for setup that way, however I would like to do all of the network configuration through wpa_cli.

The man page does not seem to have anything on hidden ssid's and when I run the set command it does not provide the output of all the variable options as stated in the man page I just get: "Invalid SET command - at least 2 arguments are required."

tldr: connect to hidden ssid through wpa_cli only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$ wpa_cli

```
> add_network 
x
> set_network x ssid "hidden_ssid"
> set_network x psk "secret"
// ALLOW CONNECT TO HIDDEN SSID 
> set_network x scan_ssid 1
> enable_network x
> save_config
> select_network x
```

**set_network x scan_ssid 1**

*where x is a network number defined in wpa cli config (see: wpa_cli list_networks)

Answer (score 5):

While not quite exactly what I was looking for, I was able to get it running.

This was through Raspbian's `rapsi-config` utility.

Steps were as follows:

- Run the `rasps-config` command with root privileges.
- Choose the second option: "Network Options"
- Enter SSID and Passphrase
- Find and open your "wpa_supplicant.conf" file. Mine is located in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
- Add the following line to the appropriate network: `scan_ssid=1`. For example:

```
network={
     ssid="NETWORK_ID"
     scan_ssid=1
     psk="NETWORK_KEY"
}
```

- Reboot, and should auto connect to hidden SSID network.